# Saving multiple items to an array using ionic and asp.net core web api

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

I am creating a shopping cart: How it works.

1. A user adds or clicks an item(**items.page**)
2. Then items are added on the **Cart-modal.page**
3. When the user opens **Cart-modal.page**, multiple items are added or displayed

Problem: The array items on the **Cart-modal.page** I want to save them.

**Class modal**

```
 export class OrderItem {
     orderitemid: number;
     quantity: string;
     itemname: string;
     itemid: number;
 }
```

**OrderService**

```
export class OrderService {
  formData: Order;
  orderItems: OrderItem[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  PostOrder() {
    var body = {
      ...this.formData,
      OrderItem: this.orderItems,
    };
    return this.http.post(environment.apiURL + "/OrderItem", body);
  }
}
```

**item.page.ts**

```
export class ItemsPage implements OnInit {
  cart = [];

  public items = new Observable<Item[]>();
  cartItemCount: BehaviorSubject<number>;

  public currentSegment: string = "All";

  @ViewChild("cart", { static: false, read: ElementRef }) fab: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    public cartService: CartService,
    private modalCtrl: ModalController,
    private router: Router,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private orderSevice: OrderService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.cartService.getProducts();
    this.cart = this.cartService.getCart();
    this.cartItemCount = this.cartService.getCartItemCount();
  }

  //start new//
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.loadContacts(this.currentSegment);
  }

  addToCart(product) {
    this.cartService.addProduct(product);
  }

  async openCart() {
    let modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: CartModalPage,
      cssClass: "cart-modal",
    });
    modal.present();
  }
}
```

**cart-modal.page.ts**

```
export class CartModalPage implements OnInit {
  cart: Item[] = [];
  formData: OrderItem;

  constructor(
    public cartService: CartService,
    private modalCtrl: ModalController,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    private orderSevice: OrderService,
    private customerservice: CustomerService,
    private navParams: NavParams,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    public navCtrl: NavController
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cart = this.cartService.getCart();
  }

  decreaseCartItem(product) {
    this.cartService.decreaseProduct(product);
  }

  increaseCartItem(product) {
    this.cartService.addProduct(product);
  }

  removeCartItem(product) {
    this.cartService.removeProduct(product);
  }

  getTotal() {
    return this.cart.reduce((i, j) => i + j.price * j.quantity, 0);
  }

  close() {
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
  }

  //it must save array OrderItems here
  submitForm() {
    this.orderSevice.PostOrder().subscribe(
      async (res) => {
        console.log("working", res);
      },

      async (error) => {
        console.log("error", error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how we can help you? what is the problem? could you explain more?

Comment: @Mazdak I cannot save multiple items that is my main problem.

Answer (score 0):

as I can understand, your repository of product items is the `CartService`, but you ask the `OrderService` to send its own `orderItems` that never filled! I can see no code to fill this `orderItems` in `OrderService`. so you should populate this array like you did in `CartService` or you should pass data to `OrderService.PostOrder(formData, orderItems)` given from `CartService`.